# I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null on jquery.main.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

This line:

```
this.textActive = this.focused || (this.element.value.length && this.element.value !== this.origValue);
```

Is producing this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

I'm not sure what's causing it, but it's creating problems.

```
refreshClasses: function() {
        this.textActive = this.focused || (this.element.value.length && this.element.value !== this.origValue);
        this.setStateClass(this.element, this.options.inputFocusClass,this.focused);
        this.setStateClass(this.elementParent, this.options.parentFocusClass,this.focused);
        this.setStateClass(this.labelFor, this.options.labelFocusClass,this.focused);
        this.setStateClass(this.element, this.options.inputActiveClass, this.textActive);
        this.setStateClass(this.elementParent, this.options.parentActiveClass, this.textActive);
        this.setStateClass(this.labelFor, this.options.labelActiveClass, this.textActive);
    },
    setStateClass: function(el,cls,state) {
        if(!el) return; else if(state) addClass(el,cls); else removeClass(el,cls);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.element.value` is most likely null, and you can't read the length of a null property. Check that property first: `(this.element && this.element.value && this.element.value.length && this.element.value !== this.origValue)`

Comment: @tymeJV Thank you for your suggestion, I'm still looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you did't consider that the `value` property could be undefined yet, instead of checking the length, check the type with `typeof`:

```
this.textActive = this.focused || (typeof this.element.value == 'undefined' && this.element.value !== this.origValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still testing your solution to see if it works in my environment. I'll update once I know.

Answer (score 0):

I've caught myself on this one as well. @Nabil is right. if the value is undefined, it naturally can't have a length.

```
this.textActive = this.focused || this.element.value && 
                      this.element.value !== this.origValue;
```

would this not work for you?

Comment: I'm still testing yours and Nabil's solution, thanks.